# @RequestMapping and @GetMapping are not mapping correctly, and I have run out of ideas for how to fix it

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on an assignment for class and for some reason the `@GetMapping` and `@RequestMapping` are not properly setting up. When I run the project and then try to access the page it only displays a WhiteLabel Error. I am using Spring Boot version 3.0.3 through Eclipse, and we are required to use Java 15 for the build path. I have spent hours trying to get this to load and I have not had any luck. I even reached out to the professor and he was not able to help.

Thank you!

```java
//Topic21Application.java
package com.gcu;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.gcu")
public class Topic21Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SpringApplication.run(Topic21Application.class, args);
        
    }

}
```

```java
//HelloWorldController.java
package com.gcu.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloWorldController {
    
    @GetMapping("/test1")
    @ResponseBody
    public String printHello()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

```xml
//topic2-1/pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gcu</groupId>
    <artifactId>topic2-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>topic2-1</name>
    <description>topic2-1</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
</properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <finalName>cst339activity</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </project>
```

```html
//hello.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
//This is for the next step of the assignment.
<h2 th:text = "${message}">This is my default text</h2><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to debug, reach out to my professor, and even ask my group for guidance but so far everyone has been at a loss. I have attempted to add the Thymeleaf add-on into eclipse and that did nothing to solve this issue. I tried accessing different pages, including `localhost:8080/hello.html`, `localhost:8080/hello/test1`, and `localhost:8080/hello.html/test1`, and all of these pages gave me the same error.

Thank you again in advance!

Comment: you still haven't told us what the error is (whitelabel just means that you don't have a custom page for error handling but you should still see the actual error there).  You should also remove the ResponseBody annotation placed on the method printHello method. This annotation tells spring boot to return a string (hello), rather than a view (hello.html). Also, you're using th:text="${message}" in your Thymeleaf template but you haven't added the message attribute to your model (e.g `Model model = new Model(); model.addAttribute("message", "hello message");` )

Comment: Also Spring Boot 3.0.3 has the problem with component scan. Check if it's the problem you have https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34379